# Hibernate JPA: How to control "Not-Found" behavior when lazy loading a ManyToOne relation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

In older xml based hibernate, one can have this config ,

`<many-to-one ... not-found="ignore" />`

but in JPA annotations, there seems to be nothing similar.

My problem is that our company has SQL REFERENCE definitions like this:

`authorId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

which makes all foreign reference default to a "Not-Found" situation. When the relation is loaded lazily, will get an Exception...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try `@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)`. It's a [Hibernate annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html).